# Flutter - Returning a CupertinoSliverNavigationBar inside a Scaffold

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to return a `Scaffold` that contains  `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar` instead of `AppBar`, or the only way is by returning a `CustomScrollView`?